# How to page refresh, if $_POST variable exists?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some post form. On click submit button, turn to another page. I need refresh page once time, if some $_POST variable exists.

Comment: I tried refresh page with javascript but it's not solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

A `POST` request is defined to update some state on the server side. A `GET` request is for requesting a resource with no side effects. So, make the `POST` to update your server, then send a redirection header to a `GET` page.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but you could try

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && !isset($_GET['refresh'])) {
  header("Location: /mypage.php?refresh");
}
```